# How to use javax.vecmath.* under Netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I downloaded javax.vecmath.* jar file from this link:

http://www.findjar.com/jar/java3d/vecmath/1.3.1/vecmath-1.3.1.jar.html

Then I added the jar file classpath by right-click the project, select Libraries under Tools, add Jar/Folder, final point the file to where I saved it. Libraries location in Ant Library Manager is Global Libraries. But I still get "package javax.vecmath package not exist" error.

What did I do wrong or what else I need to do? This is on Netbeans 7.4, JDK 1.7.0_45

Comment: What is the line of code that generates the error?

Comment: import javax.vecmath.*;

Comment: I figured it out: Don't use Libraries under Tools menu. Just right click Libraries and add the jar files to there.